# UILabel with long attributed text has a different vertical alignment than that of long plain text

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm creating a reusable view and want to allow a dataSource to define the text that appears in a header.  To make the reusable view more handy, I'd like to use a dataSource method that retrieves a `NSAttributedString` to place in the `UILabel` in the header.  The issue I'm having is that long text seems to make the text move down vertically within the `UILabel`.  Here are some screenshots.

Plain Text with a long string:
[image]

Attributed text with a long string:
[image]

My question is, why does the text move downward, and more importantly, how do I fix it.

Notes:

- Shorter text looks identical
- The Truncate Middle and Minimum Font Scale of 0.5 settings are required.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This must have been an issue in Xcode 5.0.1 or in OS X 10.9 because it's not showing up on my current system (XCode 5.0.2, OS X 10.9.2).  Here are some screenshots of a test view with 2 UILabels on it.  One is using plain text while the other is using attributed text.  They have the same font (Helvetica Neue Light 15), Autoshrink settings and text.

Plain:
[image]

Attributed:
[image]